# TreeView capture expand (or collapse) message?

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, controls

I'm trying to implement state images on my treeview; I'd like to have my own images on the buttons instead of the default + and -.

I've got an image showing, but it doesn't change when I expand the node - apparently I need to explicitly update the state image when the treeview's state changes.

Which message do I capture (in the main window procedure) to make this happen?  `TVM_EXPAND` doesn't seem to work, and various discussions online recommend strange things like hit testing a mouse click or something weird like that.

Alternatively, if there's a whizbang tutorial or something on this, please post it - I'm working off pure MSDN (ugh) and [this](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/stingray/docs/11/html/otug/14-8.html#1487) for the most part...

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q248496

Comment: Also, what means "PURE" MSDN? = WINAPI?

Comment: I mean, I'm working from the original MSDN documentation alone, not from a tutorial or user comments or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via a `WM_NOTIFY` message, you'll get `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` when an expand button is clicked and `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` when the item actually expands/collapses.